# SharePoint REST Connection to Return Data - Error

Tags: 2013, rest, error, data

I would like to ask your help to this scenario:

I am trying to return item data from a SharePoint 2013 list using REST

I am using this url:

`http://sharepointsitecollection/subsite/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('ListName')/items(1)?$select=ID,Title`

When I try to execute my code, it is returning this error:

> "readyState":0,"responseText":"","status":0,"statusText":"error"

My code is:

```
function ReturnListData() {
    try {
        //alert(document.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0]);
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://sharepointsitecollection/subsite/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('ListName')/items?$format=JSON",
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "JSON",            
            headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },               
            contentType: "application/json",
            success: function (data) {
                $.each(data.d.results, function (index, item) {
                    alert('teste');
                    //alert(item.Title);
                });
            },
            error: function (error, request, errorType, errorMessage, args) {
                alert('Error: ' + error + " - " + request + " - " + errorType + " - " + errorMessage + " - " + JSON.stringify(error));
            }
```

Could you please help me with this case?

Comment: did you get any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

I cant parse your sample code, but something like this should work...

```
    function ReturnListData() {    
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: hostweburl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('ListName')/Items",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
        success: successHandler,
        error: errorHandler
    }).done(function () {
        //console.log("RequestEnded");

    });
}

function errorHandler(data, errorCode, errorMessage) {      
    console.log("errorHandler");
    document.getElementById("lblResult").innerText =
        "Could not complete: " + errorMessage;

}

function successHandler(data) {
    console.log("successHandler");
    var jsonObject = data.d.results;        
}
```